# Orchard CMS parameterized snippet manifest file

Tags: orchardcms, manifest, code-snippets

When I add this snippet manifest JumbotronSnippet.txt for my JumbotronSnippet.cshtml

```
DisplayName: Jumbotron 
ToolboxIcon: \uf10c
Description: A configurable jumbotron
Category: Bootstrap
Fields:
    - Name: Caption
      DisplayName: Caption
      Description: The caption to display
      Type: Text
    - Name: Body
      DisplayName: Body
      Description: The body text to display
      Type: Text
```

Orchard Layout Part does not appear in dashboard.

My JumbotronSnippet.cshtml has this code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>@Model.Caption</h2>
    @Html.Raw(Model.Body)
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check snippets feature is enabled

Have you enabled the Layouts Snippets feature in the Modules menu?

It's caught me out a few times because there is a Snippets category for the Shape element but that doesn't mean that Snippets is enabled.

### Check you are running the right version

Which version of Orchard are you running? Sipke implemented the first version of the manifest file in 1.10.1 release (current).

I came along and added code to support all the extra fields that you are using but it looks like they haven't graduated to a released version yet, they are in the 1.10.x and dev branches though.

If you're already running 1.10.1 and want these features then you can just drop [this file](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/1.10.x/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Layouts/Providers/SnippetElementHarvester.cs) into your project - the only changes made to it are all contained in that file and they will just expand the number of fields supported in the manifest file parser.

### Check your manifest formatting

Here is an example one that I'm using in a client project

```
DisplayName: Facebook Panel
ToolboxIcon: \uf230
Category: Social
Description: Configurable element to display a link to a Facebook page
Fields:
  - Name: SocialUrl
    Type: Text
    DisplayName: Facebook URL
    Description: The URL to your Facebook page.
```

Straight off I am seeing its space space dash space but you have more indentation. I don't recall if the exact number of spaces will break things but the indentation is important.

Comment: Yes the Layouts snippets module is enable, I have other Snippets without a manifest file that are working like [this](https://github.com/georgeroubie/responsive-iframe-layout-snippet). I think that maybe I have a syntax error in JumbotronSnippet.txt, because when I delete the JumbotronSnippet.txt the Layout Part appears. Do you have a snippet example with a manifest, that I can see? Maybe in GitHub?

Comment: I am running Orchard 1.10.1, I replaced the SnippetElementHarvester.cs with the above file and it worked. The syntax was correct. Thank you for your response. One last question, in Orchard 1.10.2 this file will be already included?

Comment: yes its in the 1.10.x branch currently which will become the 1.10.2 release shortly. About two weeks ago Sebastien said he would start the process to release what we have currently in 1.10.x as a new patch version.